# how to send email with multiple embedded images with asp.net 4.0 with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

i just want to send email with multiple images in html body. here i want to attach each image file to html body which are already in my web application folder.

like :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>    
<title>Happy New Year - 4</title></head>
<body>  
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">  
<tbody>
<tr>   
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; background-color: #ffffff;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 688px; background-color: #ffffff; text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">     <tbody><tr>      <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; background-color: #ffffff;">       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">        <tbody><tr>         <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; background-color: #ffffff;"><div><img src=""cid:30012015_152347.jpg" alt="" /></div></td>        </tr>        <tr>         <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">           <tbody><tr>            <td style="width: 269px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;"><div><img src=""cid:30012015_152350.jpg" alt="" /></div></td>            <td style="width: 357px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; background-color: #a90100;">             <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">              <tbody><tr>               <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; background-color: #a90100;">               <div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;">                <div style="font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 13px; white-space: normal;">                 <div style="margin-top: 0px; font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 13px; white-space: normal;">Dear <b>##FirstName## ##LastName##,</b></div>                 <div style="margin-top: 4px; font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 13px; white-space: normal;">Standing on the threshold of a New Year, We send you our warmest wishes. May this year shower you with everything you desire.</div>                 <div style="margin-top: 4px; font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 13px; white-space: normal;">We wish you all the best for the year ahead.</div>                 <div style="margin-top: 4px; font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 13px; white-space: normal;">Lots of love,</div>                 <div style="margin-top: 4px; font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 13px; white-space: normal;">From your friends at:</div>                 <div style="width: 100%; font-family: trebuchet ms,verdana,"ms sans serif"; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; margin-top: 5px; white-space: normal;"><b>##UserOrganisation##</b></div>                 </div>                                  </div>               </td>              </tr>             </tbody></table>            </td>            <td style="width: 62px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;"><div><img src=""cid:30012015_152352.jpg" alt="" /></div></td>           </tr>          </tbody></table>         </td>        </tr>        <tr>         <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; background-color: #ffffff;"><div><img src=""cid:30012015_152354.jpg" alt="" /></div></td>        </tr>                </tbody></table>      </td>     </tr>     <tr>      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px;">      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 688px;">       <tbody><tr>        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border-top: 1px solid #a7a7a7; border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a7a7; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">         <tbody><tr>         <td width="50%" style="border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7; width: 50%; text-align: left;">          <div style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 8px;"><span style="font-size: 16px; color: #e92f08; font-family: trebuchet ms,verdana,"ms sans serif"; font-weight: bold;">##UserOrganisation## or<br />Logo</span></div>         </td>         <td width="50%" style="width: 50%; text-align: left;">          <div style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 8px;"><span style="font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; color: #333333; font-size: 11px; white-space: normal;"><b>Address : </b><br />##UserAddress1##, ##UserAddress2##,<br /></span><span style="font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; color: #333333; font-size: 11px;">##UserCity## - ##UserPostalCode##.</span></div>          <div style="margin: 6px 5px 5px 8px;"><span style="font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; color: #333333; font-size: 11px; white-space: normal;"><b>Phone : </b><img width="12" height="1" src=""cid:" alt="" style="width: 12px; height: 1px;" />##UserPhone##</span></div>          <div style="margin: 6px 5px 5px 8px;"><span style="font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; color: #333333; font-size: 11px; white-space: normal;"><b>FAX : </b><img width="26" height="1" src=""cid:" alt="" style="width: 26px; height: 1px;" />##UserFax##</span></div>          <div style="margin: 6px 5px 5px 8px;"><span style="font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; color: #333333; font-size: 11px; white-space: normal;"><b>Email : </b><img width="18" height="1" src=""cid:" alt="" style="width: 18px; height: 1px;" /><a target="_blank" href="mailto:##UserEmailAddress##" style="font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; color: #333333; font-size: 11px;">##UserEmailAddress##</a></span></div>          <div style="margin: 6px 5px 5px 8px;"><span style="font-family: verdana,"ms sans serif"; color: #333333; font-size: 11px; white-space: normal;"><b>Visit us : </b><img width="7" height="1" src=""cid:" alt="" style="width: 7px; height: 1px;" />&lt;Website Address&gt;</span></div>         </td>        </tr>       </tbody></table>        </td>       </tr>      </tbody></table>      </td>     </tr>    </tbody></table>   </td>  </tr> </tbody></table></body></html>
```

now examine this email body there is multiple src="cid:DDMMYYYY_HHMMSS.gif" here all files are stored in my local web applicatopn folder with unique name. i want to attach each file to email message body. (Not Email Attachment. Email Image Embedding).

how can i do with multiple images...

please help me..

Comment: this can be done through AlternateView and LinkedResource classes but how can i done with multiple images found in html body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
        SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();

        // Set sender email address, please change it to yours
        oMail.From = "test@emailarchitect.net";

        // Set recipient email address, please change it to yours
        oMail.To = "support@emailarchitect.net";

        // Set email subject
        oMail.Subject = "test html email with attachment";

        // Your SMTP server address
        SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.emailarchitect.net");

        // User and password for ESMTP authentication, if your server doesn't require
        // User authentication, please remove the following codes.            
        oServer.User = "test@emailarchitect.net";
        oServer.Password = "testpassword";

        // If your SMTP server requires SSL connection, please add this line
        // oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

        try
        {
           // Import html body and also import linked image as embedded images.
           oMail.ImportHtml( "<html><body>test <img src=\"test.gif\"> importhtml</body></html>",
                "c:\\my picture", //test.gif is in c:\\my picture
                ImportHtmlBodyOptions.ImportLocalPictures | ImportHtmlBodyOptions.ImportCss );

            Console.WriteLine("start to send email with embedded image...");
            oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);
            Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
            Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can u make one procedure to find out images with <image src ="cid:123456_123445.jpg" alt=""/> if multiple found with this

Comment: Here i just want to know is that EASendMail is freeware. and can work everytime. because this is third party tool and i want this licenced.

Answer (score 2):

u can make use of something like below...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("to_address");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string htmlBody;

            htmlBody = "Write some HTML code here";

            mail.Body = htmlBody;

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: One second are u understand my problem. i just want to send multile embeded image email. Not how to send simple mail. please read my requirenment first.

Answer (score 1):

Below code to send multiple images in the mail

```
        string subject = "Subject";
        string body = @"Image 1: <img src='src1'/> <br/> Image 2: <img src='src2'/> <br/> Some Other Content";

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("<FromAddress@mail.com>");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("<ToAddress@mail.com>"));
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        string contentID1 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
        string contentID2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");

        body = body.Replace("src1", "cid:" + contentID1);
        body = body.Replace("src2", "cid:" + contentID2);

        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");

        //path of image or stream
        LinkedResource imagelink1 = new LinkedResource(@"F:\Images\020817045614.png", "image/png");
        imagelink1.ContentId = contentID1;
        imagelink1.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink1);

        LinkedResource imagelink2 = new LinkedResource(@"F:\Images\020817045837.png", "image/png");
        imagelink2.ContentId = contentID2;
        imagelink2.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink2);

        mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

        using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("<SMTPHostAddress>"))
        {
            smtpClient.Send(mail);
        }
```

Hope this works!!